# Positioning a HTML image what is in a larger DIV

Tags: css, image, html

I want to place an image, using HTML, in a larger DIV (which is the main body of the page).

I want to position the image so that it is in the center at the top of the the DIV, but no matter what I do, the image doesn't seem to move at all!

I am happy to set the position using HTML or CSS.

This is my HTML code so far:

```
<div id="home">
    <img src="Welcome.png" alt="Welcome!" height="80px" width="200px" >

    MAIN BODY TEXT HERE 
</div>
```

and the CSS for the DIV so far:

```
#home {
    background-color: #d9d3d5;
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try using `background-image` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following CSS

```
#home img
{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @user3169325 No problem, was it just browser cache or something?

Comment: yeah, think my FTP was lagging a little. thanks again!

Comment: sorry, meant to before!

Answer (score 0):

text-align:center; would center your image

```
#home {
text-align:center;
}
```

hope this helps...